# Firestore NodeJS admin SDK, GET promise error handling for missing document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need some clarification about a point in the NodeJS admin SDK : [Firestore DocumentReference GET doc](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/DocumentReference#get) :

> Retrieve a document from the database. **Fails the Promise if the
> document is not found**.

Then in the returned Promise description :

> For missing documents, DocumentSnapshot.exists will be false. If the
> get() fails for other reasons, the Promise will be rejected.

So what's the difference between a document 'not found' and a missing document ?
Is it possible that a missing document rejects the promise ? It never happened in my tests.

In addition, I would like to know what are the most common cases where the promise is rejected (assuming that the request is made from a GCP app engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise will be resolved successfully if the document is not found, and you should check the `exists` property on the returned snapshot to check that.

The documentation is in the process of being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Pormise fails for other reasons
Documentation:

> A Promise resolved with a DocumentSnapshot for the retrieved document
>   on success. For missing documents, DocumentSnapshot.exists will be
>   false. **If the get() fails for other reasons, the Promise will be
>   rejected.**